# Best browser for HTML5 CSS3 on the middle-long term?

Tags: html, compatibility, css, browser

If you had to choose a browser (just one) to be the primarily supported browser for a company jumping into HTML5 (CSS3).. Which one would be your safest bet on the middle-long term?

Chrome, FireFox, Safari, IE?

I'm looking for an objective recommendation based on standards driven/compliant, developer tools, fast & correct feature implementations, memory footprint, etc.

UserBase/MarketShare would not be an issue because it would be on a closed environment in which we control the clients (which are basically big machines with a Web interface).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opera has always been in the lead, but they've also always had weird bugs. Right now, Chrome is in an interesting position: Google just bought an internet video protocol company (On2), and so they have the power to end the H.264 vs. Ogg Theora battle by releasing this great new codec they've bought as open source.

HTML5 itself isn't anything new: it's just new elements that display differently. Think of it like this: if HTML5 was the first to introduce the `<blink>` tag, developers would be a little iffy about it because you can just use CSS to set `text-decoration:blink` or use some Javascript to make the blinking happen.

With HTML5, things aren't that different. Most of the new elements are just extensions of `<div>`. For the ones that aren't (`<video>`, `<audio>`, `<canvas>`, etc.), there are either already strong implementations (pretty much across the board) or the implementations as complete as the HTML5 spec is.

Will there be a best browser for HTML5? Probably not. It's all just a matter of how the browsers position themselves (like I mentioned with Chrome above).

Comment: I think Chrome is positioning well for the future.

Comment: I think IE9 is the best (take a look at the demos and test results)

Comment: Alireza: They are very fast, but Chrome and Firefox are on a much faster release cycle. Firefox 5 is coming out next week. Chrome 13 is just around the corner. By year's end, all major browsers will have the same GPU enhancements that IE9 has. The lead that Microsoft has with graphics acceleration is going to be short-lived at best.

Answer (score 5):

I would say a webkit based browser. That would be the best balance of speed/stability and HTML5/CSS3 features.

However I believe that Opera has the most implemented features.

Answer (score 2):

If you control the environment I would say pick one based on that has features your app can exploit to make your job easier.  Otherwise, lower-common-denominator is a widely used approach for a small team.

Comment: We can plan on the short term features but the the middle or long term are kind of blurry. A change in browser then would imply a pretty big deployment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would say Gecko (firefox and friends) or webkit (safari, chrome and friends). I wouldn't go with IE nor Opera. Here is a [HTML5/CSS3 comparison table](http://www.texaswebdevelopers.com/html5/#summary) that pretty much supports my views.

Answer (score 0):

Safari’s pushing CSS animations and transitions, if they’re a big draw for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a HTML5 app/site that focuses on one browser, then you might as well use HTML 4 and JavaScript. For the next many many years most HTML5 sites will have to function in non-HTML5 mode.
See HTML5 features as glacing on the cake, to add benefits to the browsers that can take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

All the modern versions of browser support HTML 5. But recently launched internet explorer 9 specifically designed by keeping in mind future web technology needs and incorporated latest features that give rich and interactive web experience. [Latest browser](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/internet-explorer/products/ie/home) Internet explorer 9 has more support for Cascading Style Sheet than previous versions of Microsoft browser. It supports CSS3 and more emerging SVG2 markup standards. IE 9 includes new java script engine that designed to take advantage of multi core processor and give maximum performance.

Comment: And yet IE9 is only available for Windows 7 users, STILL isn't fully supporting w3 standards and has many proprietary quirks.  There's a reason it is down to ~20% market share from 75%+ just a few years ago.  Microsoft's web offerings = fail.